# Add a horizontal line to the chart

Tags: javascript, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

I have a requirement to have horizontal lines in Kendo Line Chart to denote maximum and minimum values as well as high limit and low limit.

Comment: I got an solution for this issue. Simply add one more line series with the chart. This will create a hr line in chart. We can manage also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be to add [plotbands](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/bar-charts/plotbands).

Example:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    valueAxis:  {
        plotBands: [
            { from: 89, to: 90, color: "red" }
        ]
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: if Kendo would just add a plotLines option so I can have dashed instead of solid lines, I would be so happy :)

Answer (score 1):

**Adding striplines or Horizontal Lines (Min/Max/Average) via Kendo-chart Render Event Handler**

[image]

I wanted to add a complete solution here so it can be used for variety reasons.

Using kendo 2015.3.1111 version, IE11/10

I had the same challenge to add upper and lower limit lines similar to MS-Chart strip lines. Kendo 2015.3.1111 and prior versions don't support this feature.

My solution is

1. Add a *stripline* property to kendo-chart value-axis property
2. Use render event handler to draw lines provided by the *stripline* property per value axis
3. A value axis (y-axis) may have multiple striplines

Make sure have the following references in the *<head>*

```
<link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the stripline property. I leave the implementation of level position up to you.

```
valueAxis: [{
            name:..
            labels:{..}   
            stripLine: [{
                value: 78,
                color: "blue",
                borderwidth: "1px",
                //"dot", "dash", "solid", "dashDot", "longDash", "longDashDot"
                dashstyle: "dot",   
                label: "In Max",
                labelposition: "",
                labelfont: "12 sans-serif"
            },
            {
                value: 70,
                color: "blue",
                borderwidth: "1px",
                dashstyle: "dot",
                label: "In Min",
                labelposition: "",
                labelfont: "12 sans-serif"
            }]
        }
```

Second Important point is the number of value axes (y-axes). Kendo-chart "value-axis" property has either the value axis or the array of value axes. Render event handler should figure out object versus array

```
render: function (e) {
            if (e.sender.options.valueAxis.length) {
                $.each(e.sender.options.valueAxis, function (i, value) {
                    drawStriptLine(e.sender, value);
                });
            }
            else {
                drawStriptLine(e.sender, e.sender.options.valueAxis);
            }
        }
```

You can see the drawStripline in the Code snippet below. Here are some notes about the code.

1. Make sure the axis names match
2. axis.slot is the data point. If you know how many data point you have, your data axis starts from 0 to your last data point number. Putting a higher number will return the last point. Otherwise line will be drawn from 0 to last point you specified in the end slot.
3. KendoChart property renderAs is optional, however canvas doesn't raise the render event handler, so use VML or SVG
4. Chrome (tested version Version 52.0.2743.116 m) doesn't support dotted and dashed lines yet (solid line only), IE11/10 supports all the dash styles
5. plotBands implementation is also demonstrated as an alternative to Render Event Handler

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

  <!--<link href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
  <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
  <!--<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="chart" />

  <script>
    var mPlotBands = [];

    mPlotBands.push({
      from: 60,
      to: 61,
      color: "red",
      borderwidth: "3px",
      borderstyle: "dashed",
      label: "Min",
      labelposition: ""
    })

     mPlotBands.push({
      from: 95,
      to: 94,
      color: "red",
      borderwidth: "3px",
      borderstyle: "dashed",
      label: "Max",
      labelposition: ""
    });


    $("#chart").kendoChart({
      renderAs: "VML", //"canvas", "SVG", "VML"
      title: {
        text: "Average In/Out Temperatures"
      },
      legend: {
        position: "bottom"
      },
      seriesDefaults: {
        type: "line"
      },
      series: [{
        name: "In Temperature",
        data: [74, 74, 76, 78, 74, 70],
        axis: "intemperature"
      }, {
        name: "Out Temperature",
        data: [45, 65, 75, 95, 80, 70],
        axis: "outtemperature"
      }],
      categoryAxis: {
        name: "CategoryAxis",
        categories: ["May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct"]
      },
      valueAxis: [{
        name: "intemperature",
        labels: {
          format: "{0}F"
        },
        min: 50,
        max: 110,
        plotBands: [],
        stripLine: [{
          value: 78,
          color: "blue",
          borderwidth: "1px",
          dashstyle: "dot", //"dot", "dash", "solid", "dashDot", "longDash", "longDashDot"
          label: "In Max",
          labelposition: "",
          labelfont: "12 sans-serif"
        }, {
          value: 70,
          color: "blue",
          borderwidth: "1px",
          dashstyle: "dot", //"dot", "dash", "solid", "dashDot", "longDash", "longDashDot"
          label: "In Min",
          labelposition: "",
          labelfont: "12 sans-serif"
        }]
      }, {
        name: "outtemperature",
        labels: {
          format: "{0}F"
        },
        plotBands: mPlotBands,
        stripLine: [{
          value: 75,
          color: "green",
          borderwidth: "3px",
          dashstyle: "dot", //"dot", "dash", "solid", "dashDot", "longDash", "longDashDot"
          label: "Out Avg",
          labelposition: "",
          labelfont: "italic 12 sans-serif"
        }]
      }],
      render: function(e) {
        if (e.sender.options.valueAxis.length) {
          $.each(e.sender.options.valueAxis, function(i, value) {
            drawStriptLine(e.sender, value);
          });
        } else {
          drawStriptLine(e.sender, e.sender.options.valueAxis);
        }
      }
    });

    function drawStriptLine(chart, yaxis) {
      var axis = chart.getAxis(yaxis.name);
      var stripline;

      $.each(yaxis.stripLine, function(i, stripline) {
        // Locate value slot
        var slot = axis.slot(stripline.value);

        // Locate last category slot. Trying to get the last slot on the right given data x-axis plots
        var categoryAxis = chart.getAxis("CategoryAxis");
        var categorySlotBeg = categoryAxis.slot(0);
        var categorySlotEnd = categoryAxis.slot(100000);

        // Render a line element
        var line = new kendo.drawing.Path({
          stroke: {
            color: stripline.color,
            width: stripline.borderwidth,
            dashType: stripline.dashstyle
          }
        });

        line.moveTo([categorySlotBeg.origin.x, slot.origin.y]).lineTo([categorySlotEnd.origin.x, slot.origin.y]);

        var labelPos = [categorySlotEnd.origin.x - 50, slot.origin.y - 20];
        var label = new kendo.drawing.Text(stripline.label, labelPos, {
          fill: {
            color: stripline.color
          },
          font: stripline.labelfont
        });

        var group = new kendo.drawing.Group();
        group.append(line, label);

        chart.surface.draw(group);
      });
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps.

References

1. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/how-to/custom-plot-bands

Answer (score 0):

Simply add one more line series with the chart. This will create a hr line in chart. We will be able to manage the line position also.